# How to select sub-document fields with mongoexport of MongoDB 4.2.1

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export a collection and have lots of embedded data that I do not need. However the entire object is being exported.

One of the sub-document is:

```
caption: {
    text: 'some text',
    // other data...
}
```

I only need the `caption.text` field (within the sub-document).

I used the export option `fields`:

```
    --fields=field1,field2,caption.text
```

as well as

```
    ---fields=field1,field2,'caption.text'
```

But in both cases, **the entire caption object is being exported**. There are no examples in MongoDB docs that show this use case.

Comment: From the `mongoexport` documentation "... if the specified field(s) is a field within a sub-document, the mongoexport _includes_ the sub-document with all its fields, not just the specified field within the document". **This is valid behavior for the export option "type=json"**. But, **with option "type-csv" you can export the specified fields**..

Comment: Note the option `type=json` is the default _type_.

Comment: OK sweet thank you, I was trying to export as JSON. I guess i will have to convert to json later